# What does "were sent" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> You were sent a new article!

I read this from an email, and does this mean "You received a new article"? Is the above sentence correct in terms of grammar?

Comment: The article _was sent_ to you, whether or not you actually received it.

Comment: The grammar is fine, an example of a verb in passive voice.